# Auto Generate @String reference in Android Studio

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio

I know that this is possible in eclipse by following the advice here: [Android: resource String automatic generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12219299/android-resource-string-automatic-generation)

But I can't seem to find if this is possible in android studio yet. Anybody know how to do this?

Basically I would like to take a hardcoded string and auto create a @string reference in my main values.xml or strings.xml.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, **Extract String Resource** while the caret is inside the hardcoded string:

[image: extract]

The same should work in XML files as well, and it does work in IntelliJ IDEA, but seems to be broken in the current version of the Android Studio:

[image: XML extract resource]

Android Studio 0.1.3 shows the folded text in XML layouts that it extracts from the string resources, but it fails to navigate back to the resource and doesn't offer to extract resources from the hardcoded strings inside XML. It appears to be a bug.

Comment: So it's like the CTRL+1 for eclipse ? wonder why all of the key combinations have changed. maybe because it's a different IDE...

Comment: @CrazyCoder is there a way to reset the options of the new IDE to work like on eclipse ? it's quite annoying to get used to totally different keys. let alone if i've changed eclipse's options... maybe there is a way to import the settings from eclipse?

Comment: It's a completely different IDE with its own set of options. There is Eclipse keymap that you can [enable in Settings | Keymap](http://img560.imageshack.us/img560/8154/20130608142429.png), but some other options may not transfer. If you are familiar with Eclipse and happy with it, you probably don't need Android Studio.

Comment: @CrazyCoder but i've noticed that it has some really cool features as shown in the google io event. sadly i don't think google will add all of those features into eclipse. choice is good, but this time i really don't know what to do. i really like features, but i'm much more familiar with eclipse.

Comment: Working in Android Studio version AI-130.737825

Comment: is it possible to have shortcut without dialog pop up?

Comment: I knew there had to be an easy way! :)

Answer (score 21):

What seems to be missing from the above answers is that, in Android Studio, you must place the cursor in the string, click the mouse, and **press Alt + Enter** to bring up the Extract String Resource dialog

Comment: Alt + Enter does not bring up an extract resource dialog in 2.2.3. Does anyone know how to do it there?

Answer (score 3):

**alt+Enter** work when your setting string resource is on,

```
how to on string resource extractor
```

> Goto Android studio 'Help' -> Find action -> type "extract string resource"

**You will find a ON / OFF button. Switch on the option.**

Comment: In 2.2.3 the option is ON but Alt-Enter still does not work.

Comment: go to inspection setting and reset project structure,