# Shortcut to quickly create/modify string in Android Studio without using strings.xml?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I searched on the web on how to modify or create a string in Android Studio, but didn't find any information on shortcuts.

I just want to modify the `@string/app_name` from `Basic App` to `My app` for example.

I know that I can manually navigate to `strings.xml` to achieve this, but is there a faster method via shortcut?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Android Studio

1. to **rename** string either file

WINDOWS <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd>

MAC <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd>

2. "extract string resource" to [create **new**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16978736/2163045) string under file *resources/string*

WINDOWS <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

MAC <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

I also encourage you guys to see **[this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eOV2owswDkE)** which shows some other trick, you may use in order to speed up your programming.

Comment: If you Alt + Enter First time it will ask for Extract String Resource -> Edit Intention Settings -> Accept the dialog.

After this you will get the direct popup to add to strings.xml file.

Answer (score 2):

Using Mac 10.5+ shortcuts, highlighting a symbol (e.g. method, reference to a resource) and pressing <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> will take you directly to where that symbol is defined.

On Windows it's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

One more option is there with plugin type

Android: Automatic string extraction

link [string extractor plugin](https://github.com/it-objects/android-string-extractor-plugin)

```
**<!-- Before, Layout: example.xml -->
<TextView
  android:id="@+id/textView"
  android:text="Hardcoded value"
  />

<!-- After -->
<TextView
  android:id="@+id/textView"
  android:text="@string/example_textView_text"
  />**
```

you can try this, and for elaboration see this [post](https://medium.com/@q2ad/android-automatic-string-extraction-ce7431d80147).