# How can I get an auto-generated string name suggestion when extracting a string resource?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

How can I get an auto-generated string name suggestion when extracting a string resource? I distinctly remember that in one of my configurations, whenever I pressed Alt-Enter, it would provide actual suggestions for my extracted strings. This saves a lot of time.

How can I set this feature?

Comment: You should write to intellij idea (jetbrains) support https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=66731

Comment: I think the link will help you [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16977208/auto-generate-string-reference-in-android-studio)

Comment: Yes I know how to extract but it used to provide a string name suggestion based on the string. I'm wondering why it doesn't anymore.

Answer (score 0):

[image]The strings can be extracted to `strings.xml` file by simply selecting/highlighting the string and pressing `Alt + Enter`, then click Extract string resource,you should get an auto suggestion for name or put your custom name and press ok after selecting strings.xml in dropdown and checking values.

you can use the same method from code as well.